# Android studio Bugs

Tags: android, mobile

Hello I am new to Android studio in the[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIxYu.png) the first project I got this error, how to fix it

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIxYu.png)

Comment: This happens when in your gradel you have specified a higher version of android and try to run it in lower version. Go to your gradel properties and look for min sdk version and change it to 29 and try again should work

Comment: I think @PriyeshJakhmola's answer should be fine. Just in case if you are wondering, minsdk is set to 31 which is android 12. having compile and target sdk as 31 is fine but since many other libraries might still be working with lower sdks, it's always a good idea to set minsdk atleast 2 or 3 versions previous to the current one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the error hasn't fix yet still having the same error.

Comment: try once with appcompact version 1.3.1

Comment: Check compile SDK version in build.gradle(app level) once 
    compileSdk 32  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/setup-sdk